# JOIN results of VLOOKUP into one string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have following task for my Google spreadsheet: JOIN strings in all cells that are to the right of certain id.

- To phrase it differently: `SELECT A, JOIN(',', B) GROUP BY A, WHERE A = myid;` if JOIN was an aggregation function.
- Or in other words: `=JOIN(',', VLOOKUP(A:B, myid, 0))` if VLOOKUP could return all occurences, not just first one.
- One picture better than of 1000 words:

[image]

Is this possible with Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you could use the `FILTER` function instead of `VLOOKUP` to filter a range based on an ID and then `JOIN` the returned range.

The documentation for `FILTER` is here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197

For example:

- You put `=UNIQUE($A:$A)` in D2 to get all the IDs.
- Then in E2 you put `=IF($D2="", "", JOIN(",", FILTER($B:$B, $A:$A=$D2)))` and then copy it down.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about FILTER, nor that its result could be simply passed to JOIN. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(B2:B<>"", {A2:A&"×", B2:B&","}, ), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 !='' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,999^99)), "×")), ",$", ), ", ", ","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you break it down a bit? My (and possibly others) case isn't as simple as the posted question and adjusting your formula feels hard without deeper understanding. A little explanation on the double query with single select statement, the data composed in the IF statement, the `999^99` and the pivoting would help. It looks like it builds up a long string of lines divided by x, then breaks it down and cleans up. The building part is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: sure, IF B column contains a value, that value is combined with a value from column A. in between is inserted unique symbol × and comma is appended at the end. then its pushed into QUERY where we create a classical pivot table. the second QUERY with 999^99 (meaning just a big number) will compress all rows of all columns into one single row. TRANSPOSE will flip the table and now we can use SPLIT by unique symbol ×. TRIM will then remove all empty extra spaces REGEXREPLACE will remove the comma from the end of the string and SUBSTITUTE will turn comma+space into just a comma. and thats pretty m

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but you can use the following (in cells E2 and E3)

```
=JOIN(",",FILTER(B:B,D2=A:A))
=JOIN(",",FILTER(B:B,D3=A:A))
```

`FILTER(B:B,D2=A:A)` will select all values in column B where there is a corresponding match on D2 to any value in column A

`JOIN` will concatenate these values into a string in a single cell (instead of showing them 1 per row from E2 downwards)

Comment: Wellcome to the party ;) Appreciate your effort, however you use the same approach already described in the accepted answer.

Comment: Whoops! My bad. I saw the UNIQUE and IF in the accepted answer, didn't read properly, and thought my answer was different. Thanks for pointing it out!