# CONCATENATE or JOIN multiple columns from VLOOKUP into single string

Tags: google-sheets, join, google-sheets-formula, concatenation

I have a worksheet with 2 tabs - Customers, Data. All tabs have a list of customers. The list on Data is a subset of all Customers. I need to pull available address information for Customers from Data.

I need the Address1-3 columns in Data to be joined using `<br>` and placed in the Address column in Customers. The situation seems [similar to this other SO thread joining results into a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684343/join-results-of-vlookup-into-one-string-in-google-sheets), however those values are all vertical in different rows and the difference here is the values are horizontal in different columns.

Not working:

- `=TEXTJOIN("<br>",1,VLOOKUP(A2,Data!A:D,{2,3,4},FALSE))`
- `=TEXTJOIN("<br>",1,QUERY("Data!A:H","SELECT B,C,D WHERE "&A2&"="&Data!A:A))`
- `=TEXTJOIN("<br>",1,FILTER(Data!A:D,A2))`

[Google Sheets example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAPyq4U5Iy8zrdLpI2FuIBYnmo7AtzsLA-kmIwdPHOs/edit?usp=sharing) ready for copy/fiddle.

**Example Data - the names have been changed to protect the innocent**

| Account | Address1 | Address2 | Address3 | City | State | Zip | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | Lorem | Ipsum | Dolor | Menlo Park | CA | 94025 | United States |
| Amazon | Sit | Amet | Consectetur | Seattle | WA | 98109 | United States |
| Apple | Adipiscing | Elit | Ut | Cupertino | CA | 95014 | United States |
| Microsoft | Ultricies | Velit | Eu | Redmond | WA | 98052 | United States |
| Google | Interdum | Bibendum | Proin | Mountain View | CA | 94043 | United States |

**Example Customers - the names have been changed to protect the innocent**

| Account | Address | City | State | Zip | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook |  |  |  |  |  |
| Walmart |  |  |  |  |  |
| Amazon |  |  |  |  |  |
| Home Depot |  |  |  |  |  |
| Apple |  |  |  |  |  |
| CVS |  |  |  |  |  |
| Microsoft |  |  |  |  |  |
| BMW |  |  |  |  |  |
| Google |  |  |  |  |  |
| Toyota |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

**Expected Output**

| Account | Address | City | State | Zip | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor | Menlo Park | CA | 94025 | United States |
| Walmart |  |  |  |  |  |
| Amazon | Sit<br>Amet<br>Consectetur | Seattle | WA | 98109 | United States |
| Home Depot |  |  |  |  |  |
| Apple | Adipiscing<br>Elit<br>Ut | Cupertino | CA | 95014 | United States |
| CVS |  |  |  |  |  |
| Microsoft | Ultricies<br>Velit<br>Eu | Redmond | WA | 98052 | United States |
| BMW |  |  |  |  |  |
| Google | Interdum<br>Bibendum<br>Proin | Mountain View | CA | 94043 | United States |
| Toyota |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is fine, you just have to wrap it in an `ArrayFormula()`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(TEXTJOIN("<br>",1,VLOOKUP(A2,Data!A:H,{2,3,4},FALSE))))
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution, to finish the formula correctly. I was hoping I could use this version because (to me) it's the most straightforward and the easiest to read.

Comment: You could also use a slight variation of the above formula that autofills the values for the entire column: `=ArrayFormula(MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(account,IFNA(TEXTJOIN("<br>",1,VLOOKUP(account,Data!A:H,{2,3,4},FALSE))))))` if you use this, enter it in cell B2 and make sure the range B3:B is empty so the formula has room to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `FILTER()` then join. Try-

```
=IFERROR(MAP(A2:A14,LAMBDA(x,JOIN("<br>",FILTER(Data!B2:D,Data!A2:A=x)))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I have never used `MAP` or `LAMBDA` before. I will have to read what these do to better understand how this works.

Comment: These are new dynamic array formula which will spill results automatically. So, you do not need to drag down the formulas to cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("<br>",QUERY({Data!A1:H6},"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&A2&"'",0)))
```

Edit: Harun24hr has the better answer, this will not autofill down.